# Get all friends' ids who liked a post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am using Facebook FQL to query `stream` table. I want to get the list of all user ids of friends who liked one of my post. Here is my query:

```
select post_id,likes.friends, likes.count from stream where source_id = me() and likes.count > 0 limit 200"
```

However, I only get maximum 4 friend ids in return, even if `likes.count > 4`, which is exactly like `likes.sample`.

Is this a bug, or a limitation of FQL? If I can't get full list of Likers here, which table I should look at? If this is not feasible with FQL, how can I make a similar query in Graph API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a multi-query on the `stream` and `like` tables

```
{"posts": "select post_id, likes.count from stream where source_id = me() and likes.count > 0 limit 200",
"friends_who_like_posts":"select user_id FROM like WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #posts) AND user_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Tommy. You save me hours on this!